# How do I copy text in textview with their fonts?

Tags: java, android

In my code, I want to copy the text to clipboard with their font. All my code does is copy the text and not the font with it. so how do I copy the text from the textbox with their fonts?

```
private TextView confetti;
private EditText input;
private ImageButton ctc;
private ClipboardManager myClipboard;
private ClipData myClip;





@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myClipboard = (ClipboardManager)getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);



    ctc = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.copy);
    ctc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String text = input.getText().toString();
            myClip = ClipData.newPlainText("text", text);
            myClipboard.setPrimaryClip(myClip);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Text Copied",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }});}}
```

Comment: A **text** is a text. It has no decorations. Only characteres. On the *receiving* View, you can decorate it as you like.

Comment: @Shreyas So where you able to achieve this?